# How to relate elements back to each other given a new list

Tags: arrays, matlab

So I have an array of elements, x and y
 `x = [11; 22; 5; 12; 42; 21; 41; 32; 10; ]`
 `y = [0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; ]`

Each element position in array x corresponds to array y elements. For example, 11 corresponds to 0, 22 corresponds to 1, 5 corresponds to 0, etc.
I went ahead and created a new array which orders the x array in ascending order:

Now given the new array:
`c =  [5; 10; 11; 12; 21; 22; 32; 41; 42]`

I want to now remake the y array so that the array aligns with the new array c, I am having trouble thinking of a way to do that in a way that is not hard coding. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the **second output of [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)**, which tells you the sorting that was applied to its input, so you can apply it to the other array:

```
[c, ind] = sort(x);
d = y(ind);
```

Comment: Thank you! You're a life savior. I have another question that I believe you would be able to answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. It looks like you already got answers to your other questions